# C# unity generator world hexagon

Tags: unity-game-engine, random, game-engine

I made some changes.
1 ° to facilitate the code temporarily, I'm using boxes.
2 ° I'm using math.PerlinNoise practice, but some grids stay away from the others.
3 ° I need to build lots with blocks but they are rounded.
So far I have been able to do this here, I will leave codes and images to try to describe my problem.

[Terrain bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5H49L.png)

[What I need to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsXVq.png)

```
public void Start()
{
    myPos = this.transform.position;
    CreateMap(CreateMapMatrix(100, 40),100, 40);

}

public Vector3[,] CreateMapMatrix(int width, int height)
{
    matrixMap = new Vector3[width, height];

    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < height; z++)
        {

            float h = Mathf.PerlinNoise((seed + myPos.x + x) / width,
                (myPos.z + z) / height) * x;

            h = Mathf.Floor(h);

            matrixMap[x, z] = new Vector3(h, 0, z);
        }

    }

    return matrixMap;

}



    void CreateMap(Vector3[,] pos, int width, int height)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < height; z++)
            {
                GameObject Obj = Instantiate(hexTransform[0]);
            Obj.transform.position = pos[x,z];

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: could not understand the question here.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I'm Brazilian.
I need to make a method in which the world's generation of platforms without holes, my world is world bumpy and with very narrow passages.

Comment: A coarse suggestion would be to make a second pass over your world generation to clean up any minor undesirable features.

Comment: I was able to create something, but it did not go as I intended.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using **Perlin Noise** to accomplish world generation. Games like Minecraft and Raft utilize it.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.PerlinNoise.html

https://forum.unity.com/threads/open-source-procedural-hexagon-terrain.233296/

Comment: I took a look and understood a little, but the result did not go exactly as I needed it.
For I need that the blocks do not unite one inside the others and always one next to the other, without spaces.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Can you please be a little more descriptive?

Comment: I need to make a terrain generator, I'm trying to implement PerlinNoise but it's not coming to a result.

Comment: How bout this? https://forum.unity.com/threads/open-source-procedural-hexagon-terrain.233296/